# update only null value columns in table if ID exits in table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector, azure-mysql-database

I am trying to check for the `ID`. If it does not exist I want my data to be inserted as a new record in table and if `ID` exists I want to compare both incoming new record and existing record and only update the values which are `null` in existing record. I have written the query but I don't know how to check for `null` in each column:

Here is the query:

```
insert into ui_table(MDMID,FirstName,Lastname,Mail,Address,City,State,Zip,ProfileStatus,TAID)
select im.MDMID,im.FirstName,im.Lastname,im.Mail,im.Address,im.City,im.State,im.Zip,im.ProfileStatus,im.TAID
from intermediate im on duplicate key update 
    MDMID = im.MDMID, 
    FirstName = im.FirstName,
    Lastname = im.Lastname,
    Mail = im.Mail,
    Address = im.Address,
    City = im.City,
    State = im.State,
    Zip = im.Zip,
    ProfileStatus = im.ProfileStatus,
    TAID = im.TAID;
```

Comment: `ODKU column = COALESCE(column, im.column)`?

Comment: insert into ui_table(MDMID,FirstName,Lastname,Mail,Address,City,State,Zip,ProfileStatus,TAID)
select im.MDMID,im.FirstName,im.Lastname,im.Mail,im.Address,im.City,im.State,im.Zip,im.ProfileStatus,im.TAID
from intermediate im on duplicate key update
    ui_table.MDMID = IFNULL(NULLIF( ui_table.MDMID,''),im.MDMID);

Comment: I have used this one is this correct?

Comment: You tell ".. and **only** update the values **which are null** in existing record". So you do not need to update empty string, and NULLIF() usage is not correct.